# Pull business info from QR code

Tags: android, google-maps, qr-code

I am not sure if this can be done. I am trying to pull a business info (mainly business name) from QR code. I am using zxing and I am able to scan it and get the URL. Now is there any other hidden info such as business name, address ..etc  that I can pull from the QR code. If not, then can I use the URL maybe to get some of these info? Pleeease any insight is appreciate to how it can be achieved

PS: Ultimitally, I want the business to be shown on google map. Thats all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the company name is recorded in a standard format in the QR code, like [vCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) encoding using the "ORG" attribute, then yes you can parse the raw text you get back by Intent from Barcode Scanner zxing using its `ResultParser` class. It will detect and parse vCard and you will get an `AddressBookParsedResult` object with an "org" property with this info.

Otherwise you're talking about guessing from free-form text what the company name is. There's no way to do that with zxing and that's a generally hard problem.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the info. That does help confirm what I have been guessing